# Rails. Applying conditional code to a after validation callback: geocode on the city or ip address depending on whats availlable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, geocode

I have the following code in my User model.

```
  geocoded_by :city

  after_validation :geocode, if: ->(user){ user.city.present? and user.city_changed? }
```

Initially the user does not have to input their city so these users will not be geocoded. Is there an way to run conditional code on a call back, so if no city, geocode by ip_address, if city geocode by city?

I accept this is a basic question but I have had difficulty finding info on applying conditional code to a call back

tried

```
if self.city.present?
   geocoded_by :city
 else
   geocoded_by :ip_address
end
```

without success

Comment: Put an `if` in your `geocode` method.

Comment: See above - doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#model-configuration) you can pass a method to `geocoded_by`:

```
geocoded_by :geo_attr

def geo_attr
  if self.city.present?
     self.city
   else
     self.ip_address
  end
end
```